# Is There A Quick Way of Listing "A:/" - "Z:/"

Tags: java

```
Object[] possibilities = { "A:/", "B:/", "C:/" };
        String drive = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Pick a Drive", " ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                possibilities, "C:/");
```

Is there a quicker way to make the options "A:/" to "Z:/" in `possibilities` without having to write every letter out?

Comment: Why don't you just do it in a loop?

Comment: Listing A-Z would be invalid anyway, because not all Windows computers have all 26 possible drive letters in use. See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320/find-all-drive-letters-in-java) for how to list all drive letters that exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to fill your array with all drive letters from A-Z, the following loop should work (assuming you declare `poss` with a length of 26 or greater):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    poss[i] = (char) ('A' + i) + ":/";
}
```