# how to find all the files of given extension in whole harddisk

Tags: java

i have written a program that finds all the files of specified type by passing its extension.
my problem is, program is finding files in C drive only, but i want to search in for whole hard disk. here is my program sample

```
public class Find {

public static class Finder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private final PathMatcher matcher;
    private int numMatches = 0;

    Finder(String pattern) 
    {
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    }

    // Compares the glob pattern against
    // the file or directory name.
    void find(Path file) 
    {
        Path name = file.getFileName();
        if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) 
        {
            numMatches++;
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }

    // Prints the total number of
    // matches to standard out.
    void done() 
    {
        System.out.println("Matched: "+ numMatches);
    }

    // Invoke the pattern matching
    // method on each file.
    //@Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,BasicFileAttributes attrs) 
    {
        find(file);
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    // Invoke the pattern matching
    // method on each directory.
    //@Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,BasicFileAttributes attrs) 
    {
        find(dir);
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    //@Override
   public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,IOException exc) 
    {
        System.err.println(exc);
        return CONTINUE;
    }
}

static void usage()
{
    System.err.println("java Find <path>" +" -name \"<glob_pattern>\"");
    System.exit(-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
{

    if (args.length < 2 ) 
    {
        usage();
    } 
    Path startingDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
    String pattern = args[1];

    Finder finder = new Finder(pattern);
    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
    finder.done();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the difference between "C drive only" and "whole hard disk"?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "return" statement after the call to usage() in the main method?

Comment: i have used exit function for that

Comment: This tutorial will help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: in windows a user may create as many partitions as he wish and they call them drives. and in window all partitions have their labels for example C, D,E and so on.. my mean to say whole hard disk is to search in these user created partitions   @Tichodroma

Comment: @VigneshVino yes this tutorial really boosted my capability. i code my program(this one)  by reading this article :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all drive letters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320/find-all-drive-letters-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `File.listRoots()` method to find all drives on Windows. After that just do an independent search on each drive.

Using the new API (java.nio.file) there's another way: `FileSystem.getDefault().getRootDirectories()`.

```
for (Path startingDir : FileSystem.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
    // find files here
}
```

Comment: i listened a lot about listRoots method but yet not go through it. so please can you elaborate?? please @Joni

Comment: please share something regarding ur post that can help me

Comment: Since you're using the new path API it's better to use the second approach; see update.

Comment: ok i will back to you later with my effort's result ... thanks a lot :)

Comment: yesssssss    i make it....

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
  File folder = new File("D:\\DestFile");
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

  for (File file : listOfFiles) {
   if (file.isFile()&&   (file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.')+1).equals("your_type"))) {// txt or docx or something
     // do something
    }
    }
```

Try this. you can read all file in your PC by this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] paths = File.listRoots();
    for(File directory:paths){
       getFile(directory.toString());
    }
}

public static void getFile(String directoryName) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if(fList!=null){
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                getFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i appreciate your response. but i want my program to be generalize. means it will search for all the partitions, not in specified partition

Comment: There should a minor change in your program `if(dir.isFile() && dir.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("Test.java")){
      System.out.println("GetFileNames.main():" + dir.getName());
    }else{
      File[] listOFFiles = dir.listFiles();`