# Merging my own Directory Tree class with JTree for use on Swing

Tags: java, swing, tree, jscrollpane, jtree

I have built my own K-ary tree, which contains nodes storing data about a file system entries. I would like to be able to display this in a `JScrollPane` or something similar. I've now found the `JTree` class, but am struggling to find how to efficiently translate the information from my tree to the `JTree`, while still maintaining my tree functionality, for example I'd like to be able to select a node from the `JTree` and get the information from my own tree.

```
public class DirectoryTree implements Serializable {

    private TreeNode Root;
    private int numNodes;

    private TreeNode Focus;
    private LocalDateTime date;

    private long totalSizeOnDisk;
```

I had originally decided to create a class `NodeWithButton`, and create a tree hierarchy on a scroll pane using buttons, but I would have to recursively create them and their listeners and it all became a little too much to deal with.

Comment: Swing is based on data models.  When you have your own data that you want a Swing component to display, you write your own model which wraps your data.  In this case, you should write your own implementation of [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html).

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Comment: @VGR You mean I should write another class which implements TreeModel and contains an object of my DirectoryTree, and then ask the JScrollPane to display that?

Comment: Yes to the first part, but JScrollPane has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks! This will help greatly.

Comment: See also the `FileTreeModel` cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34224804/230513).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this, it was a fairly simple solution.

JScrollPane takes a TreeModel as an argument for the constructor, so with the tip from VGR in the comments, I just made a new class DirectoryTreeModel, which implemented TreeModel, and contained an instance of my DirectoryTree and then overwrote the methods with my own tree functions.
e.g.:

```
@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {

    TreeNode p = (TreeNode) parent; //got to cast the object class into my TreeNode class
    return p.getChildren().get(index);

}
```