# JTree displaying drive does not show up at all

Tags: java, swing, file, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

My task is to show a tree of all directories/files of a PC drive,
I have a class `DirectoryNode` that extends `DefaultMutableTreeNode` with `File` field `directoryPath`. I build nodes recursively:

```
public void buildDirectoryTree(){
    if(!directoryPath.isDirectory()){
            return;
    }

    for(File f : directoryPath.listFiles()){
        if(f.isHidden() || !f.exists()) continue;
        DirectoryNode newChild = new DirectoryNode(f);
        add(newChild);
        newChild.buildDirectoryTree();
    }
}
```

It works fine for concrete directories, but when I try to use it for whole drive, or some large directories, `JTree` with this node does not show up at all
I think it encounters a problem with specific directories. I've add exists and is Hidden checks to skip this problem roots, but it didn't help.

In addition, `exists`, `isHidden` and `isDirectory` return `false` for some of my valid directories directories (I am using Windows 10).

Comment: First, I'd use the nio2 `Path` API rather than `File`, as `File` doesn't like symbolic links. I'd also be careful with scanning a whole drive and make sure you're using a "lazy" loading approach, so you only load what you need to display

Comment: 1) See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784). It builds each part of the tree on user selection of a directory, the main reason for that is that it takes a loooooong time to build a tree of an entire (typical) drive. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Also consider this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34224804/230513) that uses a `FileTreeModel`.

Answer (score 1):

`File.listFiles()` is one of those ancient methods that violates Java's convention/good practice to never return `null` from a method that returns an array. So you have to check for `null`.

From the docs:

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

I have changed your code to make it a little safer. If it's called from the EDT, you might want to add some log message or the like instead of throwing the exception into nirvana.

```
public void buildDirectoryTree() throws IOException {
    if (!directoryPath.isDirectory()) {
            return;
    }
    final File[] files = directoryPath.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isHidden() || !f.exists()) continue;
            DirectoryNode newChild = new DirectoryNode(f);
            add(newChild);
            newChild.buildDirectoryTree();
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Failed to list files for " + directoryPath);
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, there are more modern APIs and they have been introduced for good reasons. I recommend to read up on NIO2 and the `Path` APIs for better solutions.